# Image Display not showing in Custom Spinner Adapter

Tags: java, android

i am using following code to attach an image placed in my asset Folder

```
  ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new CustomArrayAdapterForCurrencies(this, currenciesDataSource.keys);
      paidIn.setAdapter(adapter);


viewHolder.flag = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.UICurrencyCurrencyFlag);
            String filename = "Images/Currencies/" + keys[position] + ".png";
            try {
                InputStream bitmap= context.getResources().getAssets().open(filename);
                Bitmap bit=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bitmap);
                viewHolder.flag.setImageBitmap(bit);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

[image: With Image]

But when i click on Spinner following this happens,
If i click on let us say , INR, The indian flag shows up just like above, but i want all the flags to be shown in this screen too.

[image: No Image]

Please tell me what is the problem Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

If PaidIn is a spinner ,then you must have set a DropDownViewResource layout file for it using `setDropDownViewResource()`. Use a custom layout file with an imageview and textview as your drop down resource, then you will be able to shown Indian and other flag images too... For example:

```
Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
                items);

        aa.setDropDownViewResource(
           android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin.setAdapter(aa);
```

Comment: ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new CustomArrayAdapterForCurrencies(this, currenciesDataSource.keys);
      paidIn.setAdapter(adapter); This is all what i have used.... what should i do now?

Comment: adapter.setDropDownViewResource() for adapter you use for spinner. I did a typo. It is a property of the adapter. Check the edited code. just specify your custom layout file in that method and you are good to go.